# How to use jQuery UI icons without buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

jQuery UI comes with some good icons.
How can I use them without buttons? Let's say how to create link with *plus* sign and to react on hover and click by changing icons?
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/gZQzt/) is the demo just with icon added.

**Upd 1:**
On hover icon should change the color from grey to black (please see it [here](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/static/icons.html)). In my demo it is black from the beginning.

**Upd 2:**
Here is almost what I need - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/gZQzt/6/ - but without that background rectangle, I need just plus sign.

**Upd 3:**
Looks like it would be better not to use standard jQuery UI styles, but to refer directly to the [images](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/themes/base/images/), but I don't know how use it.

Seems I need to define CSS like:

```
width: 16px; 
height: 16px; 
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);
background-position: -32px -128px;
```

Positions can be easily found at [jquery.ui.theme.css](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/smoothness/jquery.ui.theme.css) file.
But how should I:

1. define correct background-image url?
2. modify CSS to react on click, hover?

Comment: Can you clarify your question more? You already used the correct classes etc., so I guess refering to the CSS `a:hover { ... }` is not necessary here.

Comment: updated my answer so it responds to hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've decided just to use jQuery UI's image files - [How to use one icon from different image files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047684/how-to-use-one-icon-from-different-image-files):

```
a:link,a:visited { /* for regular non-hovered, non-active link styles */
    width: 16px;  
    height: 16px;
    background-image:
    url(images/defaultStateImage.png); 
    background-position: -32px -128px;
}

a:hover { /* for hover/mouse-over styles */
    url(images/hoverStateImage.png); 
    background-position: -32px -128px;
}

a:active { /* for click/mouse-down state styles */
    url(images/clickStateImage.png); 
    background-position: -32px -128px;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the icons with any element by adding the `ui-icon` and the appropriate class for the icon you want to the element.

```
<a href="#" class="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"></a>
```

If you want to add text to the link as well as an icon you'll need to set the icon on a separate element from the text.  For example:

```
<a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"></span><span>Text Here</span></a>
```

To change the icon on hover, you'll need to use some javascript.  The following requires jQuery:

```
$(".MySelector").hover(function() { 
    $(this).removeClass("ui-icon-plusthick").addClass("ui-icon-minusthick");
}, function() { 
    $(this).removeClass("ui-icon-minusthick").addClass("ui-icon-plusthick");
});
```

Comment: Obviously you haven't tested this. ui-icon sets a fixed width, so it's not possible the set any link text unless you use additional CSS rules for the width.

Comment: I have tested this, but didn't think to mention that.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: I see the hover requirement in your post now, but it wasn't there when I answered the question.  See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, @Kyle. But again it doesn't work properly - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/gZQzt/5/ - firstly, icon is not changed back. Secondly, incorrect icon is used (how to extract that grey plus icon, which is used with standard jquery button?).

Comment: *sigh* don't answer within the first 10 minutes of consciousness, Kyle.  Sorry, that was an incomplete JS snippet.  I edited the answer to fix it.  This should now revert the icon after you mouse off the button.  To change the icons you want displayed just replace the classes with another icon class.  I used plusthick and minusthick for my example, but you can use others.

Comment: Here's a list of all the available icons: http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/jqueryui-icons/

Comment: Thanks, Kyle. It is better now - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/gZQzt/7/. But looks like there is no separate style for grey `ui-icon-plusthick`, so this approach will not work for me. I've updated my question with another possible approach... PS. There is `ui-state-hover`, but it adds rectangle...

Comment: You can customize the look and feel of the icons and other elements by using at jQuery UI Theme.  Take a look a the themeroller:  http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/.  The `ui-state-hover` class doesn't change the icon, it merely adds the background/border to the element.

Answer (score 8):

This is not "good", but at least this works.
Please specify your question further, what should happen on click and hover.

### Sample

http://jsfiddle.net/gZQzt/2/

### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="img-link">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" style="display:inline-block;"></span>
    <span class="link-text">Link</span>
</a>
```

### CSS

```
.img-link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.link-text {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<a>
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"></span>
</a>
```

and:

```
$('a').hover(function(){$(this).toggleClass('ui-state-highlight')});
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/gZQzt/4/

Comment: I've tested this in the latest version of FF - when mouse is over that icon it is constantly refreshing (and even some blue plus is displayed near normal plus) - this is surely what I don't want to have.

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't reply to answers yet, here's what I did using Kyle Traubermann's code:

```
<div class="ui-state-default" style="background: none; border: none;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-tick"></span></div>
```

Basically, you have to put the state in a separate div. This changes the image to the right colour but it also adds a border and gloss to it so I had to disable that with nones. You might need a color: none; in there as well.

There's probably a simpler way to do this but I don't really know much about CSS yet.

Comment: I have no idea what jsfiddle is doing but you need to include the css as well: 
http://durand1.co.cc/dump/jqueryui_icons/icons.html

I also made a mistake. The icon is called check, not tick but the rest of the code should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

UI icon as anchor (no text):

Works for me:

```
<a href="http://wow.com"><span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-extlink"></span></a>
```

Relevant: order of ui class names.